# Application crashes with Exception when using javax.microedition.media.Player

Tags: blackberry, java-me, mmapi

I have an application that processes data from bluetooth and send it to the web service. Recently there was a request to add sounds to the application. Now when the application processes batches of data and the player is playing constantly after a few secs I get "Application is not responding" exception. And then the process is terminated. In the logs I can see lots of ForcedStackTrace exception logged after this exception.

The sounds are played in the separate thread. If app doesn't play sounds or plays short sounds - everything works fine. Is there any way to avoid this exception happening? Why is it happening?

```
InputStream mediaStream = null;
try {
    mediaStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(relativePath);
    getLogger().log("setting player _ " + _audioType);
    setPlayer(Manager.createPlayer(mediaStream, _audioType));
    _currentPlayer.addPlayerListener(this);
    _currentPlayer.setLoopCount(1);
    _currentPlayer.realize();
    VolumeControl vc = (VolumeControl) _currentPlayer
            .getControl("VolumeControl");
    if (vc != null) {
        vc.setLevel(_voumeLevel);
    }
    _currentPlayer.prefetch();
    _currentPlayer.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

*(crossposted from BB forums)*

Comment: Could you specify exact version of JDE?
How exactly do you create Player (any specific parameters are welcome)?

Comment: I use JDE 4.0.2 libraries to compile. Project is Eclipse based.

Comment: You can always edit your question, and answer as well ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by implementing my own PlayerManager, which, running in a separate thread would play the item in the queue manner rather then having many threads using the inner Player implementation.